# how to handle textfield on image in netbeans

Tags: java, swing

I have to add 3 text field over an image. How do I do that? I have been unable to do this using the drag and drop features of netbeans. I am not able to drag and drop text field on the image.

Answer (score 1):

1. Draw your image as the background on a JPanel
2. Add your text fields to the panel.

The basic logic for the custom painting of the image on the panel would be:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Dimension d = getSize();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, d.width, d.height, null);
}
```

Another option is to add the text fields to a JLabel. You just need to set the layout manager of the label before you add the components.

Or you can check out [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for a class that gives various painting options.